# What is this red-flowered bulb with red fruits?

Tags: identification, bulbs

I took the picture a few days ago in a botanical garden in Spain. Which species is it?

[image: clivia]

Answer (score 4):

This is a [clivia miniata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clivia_miniata), also known as Natal lily, bush lily or Kaffir lily.

It's a relative of [Amaryllis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaryllis) (belladonna lily, not to be confused with [Hippeastrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippeastrum)) native to southern Africa and a popular house plant in cooler regions.

The plant is poisonous, so do not eat the red fruit.